# ptrace can't work well in kernel 2.6 for mips in qemu?

Tags: kernel, mips, qemu, ptrace

I want to use ptrace in qemu mips, but I can't wake up the child process when using fork and attach, however, I got success in kernel 3.2. 
I hope to know why got this ques in kernel 2.6?

I got the kernel from

https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/mips/

Comment: MIPS is an officially supported architecture, you shouldn't need to use anything but the mainline kernel.

Comment: especially, if you're debugging something, maybe images from 2013 aren't the wisest choice, since everyone else might have moved on

Comment: thx, I need to monitor something in kernel 2.6, and ptrace in kernel 2.6 is necessary.

Comment: Show us your code. Create a minimal example showing what you tried and what you expected it to do. There is absolutely nothing here we can work with.

Comment: Also, is this just an old kernel, or is the user space also old? Where and how are you building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this pro. I use kernel 2.6.32, and this kernel had a bug for ptrace mips and I got from here, https://sourceforge.net/p/strace/mailman/message/31856938/,

and the patch is here, http://gitlab.pedjaapps.net/pedja/lge-kernel-omap4/commit/55436c91652b45be576b91ec96a8d65f6b7447fa

and I patch it and recompile the kernel and then ptrace work well.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot really answer your question, because it contains no usable information, so I'll just guess. Some of the ptrace constructs available were introduced into Linux later than the kernel you are using.

If you are using `PTRACE_TRACEME` or `PTRACE_ATTACH`, than you should be fine. If you are using `PTRACE_SEIZE`, then you are using a mechanism that simply did not exist in the kernel version you are using.

Comment: thanks for your help, and I solved this pro. I use kernel 2.6.32, and this kernel had a bug for ptrace mips and I got from here, https://sourceforge.net/p/strace/mailman/message/31856938/, and the patch is here, http://gitlab.pedjaapps.net/pedja/lge-kernel-omap4/commit/55436c91652b45be576b91ec96a8d65f6b7447fa

Comment: and I patch it and recompile the kernel and then ptrace work well.

Comment: Then write it as an answer, so that anyone else who happens to come across the same problem can find the solution.